# While launching AVD in emulator showing this "Unable to locate adb"

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

[image: error]

It was working before but after 4.0 update it's not working.

Errors are

> 08:55 AM  Emulator: C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'
> 08:55 AM    Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

and yes I don't have antivirus.

Answer (score 10):

Reinstalling Android SDK after deleting the platform-tools dir doesn't work for everyone follow these steps, they may help you:

1. In Android Studio go to **File>Project Structure** (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S in windows);
2. The **Project Settings>Project>Project SDK** must have a valid Android SDK selected;
3. Start the **adb-server** daemon with **adb.exe start-server** (this is to avoid the: **adb** **wasn't listening on port XXXX** error message);
4. Emulate a new device (if you've added **%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator** to your path run **emulator.exe -list-avds** select one of the virtual devices from the list and run **emulator.exe -avd** , if not find out your Android SDK path and change the previous commands accordingly);
5. check if the **adb** daemon is running and recognizes the emulated device: open cmd prompt, run **%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\adb.exe devices** and it should list the device you have on at the moment.

Comment: For me under Project Settings>Project>Project SDK was not set.

Answer (score 0):

1. on your android studio go to Tools > android > SDK Manager.
2. view android SDK location (this will show you your sdk path)
3. navigate to file explorer on your system, and locate the file path, this should
   be found something like c://Users/johndoe/AppData/local/android (you
   can now see the sdk.)
4. check the platform tools folder and see if you would see anything like adb.exe (it should be missing probably because it was corrupted and your antivirus or windows defender has quarantined it)
5. delete the platform tools folder
6. go back to android studio and from where you left off navigate to sdk tools (this
   should be right under android sdk location)
7. uncheck android sdk platform-tools and select ok. (this will uninstall the platform
   tools from your ide) wait till it is done and then your gradle will
   sync.
8. after sync is complete, go back and check the box of android
   sdk platform-tools (this will install a fresh one with new adb.exe)
   wait till it is done and sync project and then you are good to go.

Comment: In "c://Users/johndoe/AppData/local/android".  Is  don't have that AppData file,   now what i do

Comment: Locate your SDK in your PC, and follow steps

Comment: hay, i'm  still geting this error :-       {16:22 Emulator: C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

16:22 Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot}